# Multiple parameter in DB2

Tags: jquery, db2

I am using jquery and db2. I am getting below error in execution time

```
Error:SQL:The OdbcParameterCollection only accepts non-null OdbcParameter type objects, not OleDbParameter objects.
```

**My DB2 sql**

```
Create procedure myparameters(
IN vname VARCHAR(500),
IN vurl VARCHAR(1000),
IN vyear VARCHAR(10),
IN vmonth VARCHAR(10)
)
language sql
BEGIN ATOMIC
SET vname = '~p_hostname~'; -- these tild values are coming from jquery
SET vurl = '~p_url~';
SET vmonth = '~p_month~';
SET vyear = '~p_year~';
select hour as hours,tvalue as seconds from myschema.my_view
WHERE  
    name = vname and
    url= vurl and
    month = CAST(vmonth AS INT) and
    year = CAST(vyear AS INT) and
    VALUE_TYPE ='access Time'
order by hour;
END@
```

Comment: Please check if you pass null value to vname (or any other parameter) and use predicat like name = vname. In this case you should get error. Use "IS NULL" to check for null value or predicate like "NAME = COALESCE(VNAME, '')"

Comment: I think we're going to need to see your Java code, too, given that error message.  And does the SQL you've given us actually run?  It appears to be otherwise valid...  @Alexey - Unfortunately, the error message is suggesting that the null is coming from the Java side.  While checking for a passed null is good advice, the rest is less helpful; for one thing, comparing null to anything with '=' won't ever return an error.  And the comparison using `COALESCE()` will change the semantics of the query, which may not be what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved

```
    //I defined variable in jquery like this:
var parameter;
parameter += '|p_hostname=' + $('#hname').val();
parameter += '|p_url=' + $('#hurl').val();
parameter += '|p_month=' + $('#hMonth').val();
parameter += '|p_year=' + $('#hYear').val();

--db2 SQL--
select 
    url as URL
    ,hour as Time
    ,value as URL_Time
from myschema.my_view 
where 1=1
    and name = '~p_hostname~' 
    and url ='~p_url~'
    and cast(month as int) = cast('~p_month~' as int) --Problem occured here
    and cast(year as int) = cast('~p_year~' as int) --Problem occured here
    and VALUE_TYPE ='access Time'
order by
    hour;
```

Error has gone after doing above modification.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled the SP in DB2? That SP does not work, what are you going to do? fill values from the select in local variables? return the cursor to the caller?

First, make  sure your SP works in DB2, and after that try to use from an external application. Where did you get that error? are you sure the SP shown is the one in the DB?

When you have a problem in DB2, the most important thing to show is the SQLCODE. Texts and message are meaningless to understand the problem.

Also, check the SP, a varchar column can be 256 char max, and you have it with 1000.  In the opposite way, small char columns is better to use CHAR instead of VARCHAR to reduce the overhead.